# difference between HSI & YCbCr related with skin color

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, rgb

I m doing project on face detection in c#, i want to find skin area by using skin color segmentation, for that pupose i have to extract skin area, now i can use HSI & YCbCr , what is the exact difference between these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `HSI` and `YCbCr` are based on the idea of separating the brightness component from the color component.

`I`  in `HSI` is (roughly) the equivalent of `Y` in `YCbCr`.
`H` and `S`  in `HSI` is (roughly) a polar representation of `Cb`, `Cr` in `YCbCr`. For the *exact* difference check the formulas.

It might be a bit more convenient for you to work in polar coordinates (`HSI`), since skin tone is located in a specific `H` range.